# What's wrong with this MySQL INSERT query

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm trying to insert the data below into an existing table, and it gives me sql error 1064, you have an error in your sql syntax at line 3.

```
INSERT INTO `static_contract` (`ID`, `contractID`, `name`, `mobbaseID`, `classID`, `dialogID`, `menuoptions`, `iconID`, `notes`, `vendorID`, `pTable`, `sTable`, `itemModTable`, `allowedBuildingTypeID`)
VALUES
(2026, 2026, 'Premium Vendor', 15312, 1906, 600, '1 2 15 18', 68, 'vendor', 0, '0', '0', '', 0),
```

Here's the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `static_contract` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contractID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mobbaseID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `classID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dialogID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `menuoptions` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `iconID` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notes` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `vendorID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pTable` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sTable` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `itemModTable` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `allowedBuildingTypeID` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `fk_contracts_mobbase` (`mobbaseID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=302900 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: There is more explanation in the error message, which points **exactly to the problem**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma outside of your parenthesis at the end is the problem. Please select an answer to mark this question as complete.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I believe it is complaining about the comma at the end of your statement **on line 3.**

Second, you are putting a value into an auto-increment column **ID.**

Third, why are you specifying every column to insert into if you're inserting something in every column? Just do:

```
INSERT INTO static_contract VALUES (...)
```

Comment: "Third" - in case of another column (nullable or with default value) is added - the current solution won't brake. But your proposal will.

Comment: I specified the ID because I already had entries that I wanted these new entries to have ID values similar to.